# Pass dataframe column values as String in dbduck sql query using loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using dbduck to run sql query on the following dataframe `df`:

[image]

In this sql, I need to pass the values from dataframe col3 using a loop:

```py
aa = ps.sqldf("select * from result where col3= 'id1'")
print(aa)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate on the values of `col3` like this, using Python [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings):

```py
for v in df["col3"]:
    aa = ps.sqldf(f"select * from result where col3='{v}'")
    print(aa)
```